# Selenium IDE: A test case with many different values

Tags: selenium-ide

I have a test case which is repeated with 100 different values. It is hard to write 100 test cases, so how can I write a test case for all values?

I am using Selenium IDE in Firefox to write a test-suite for a website.

Comment: please share your actual scenario that what you want to test and achieve?

Comment: use selenium ide to save as a language you know how to use, convert the altering test parameter into a program parameter and then loop over the 100 values

Answer (score 1):

What types of values are they? Are they similar other than say an increment (say. A1, A2, A3), or just 100 random values?  Is the expected outcome the same for each value? More information on your scenario is needed to assist.

I've used the SelBlocks plugin for doing while loops.

Answer (score 0):

put the 100 values into a array: like values=[1,2,3,4,5,6......]; then

```
it('test case name', function() {
    for (i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
        console.log(values[i]);
    }
});
```

write your test case in for loop